# Action method expected parameter named Id and nothing otherwise

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **The Error**
>
> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'UserId'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Int64' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Predict(Int64)' in
>   'sportingbiz.Controllers.PredictionController'. An optional parameter
>   must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an
>   optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

This does not work. Throws the error mentioned above

```
http://mysite/User/Profile/15
```

This works

```
http://mysite/User/Profile/?UserID=15
```

The Controller Action

```
public ActionResult Profile(long UserID)
{

}
```

When I changed the parameter name to `Id` it works. I think it's because `Id` was specified in the route collection (Global.asax). Is it possible to tell MVC that `UserId` should map to `Id` without changing it in the `Global.asax`

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the side effect of changing `UserID` to `id` in the `Profile` method? Why are you trying to avoid it?

Comment: I have actually done that now. Before, generating links in markup using Id, I couldn't recognise which Id, but I thought if I could use UserID, ContactID, I would know which Id am passing

Answer (score 5):

The only way to accomplish this (without getting into custom ModelBinders, which gets really hairy) is to:

1. make the parameter nullable
2. use the *RouteData* collection to set the property after-the-fact.

---

```
 public ActionResult Profile(long? UserID)
 {
     UserID = UserID ?? long.Parse((string)RouteData.Values["id"]);
 }
```

Comment: the code you posted before didn't work. I was just testing to be double-sure

Comment: @codingbiz that is correct, sir.  I thought it would work, but then unfortunately I decided to test it...

Answer (score 0):

I would always make the id param on a controller something generic like Id, then you dont have to create lots of routes to match the different id types.

If you aren't using a string which is nullable for your id, you can provide a default value such as long id = 0 and handle the zero value as being the default starting sequence.

For example, in a paging method, you can set it to zero so you dont need any params on the first page, but passing it thereafter will request that page number etc etc

Si

Answer (score 0):

I think the code already posted should work so I tested my version and it worked:

```
public ActionResult Profile(long? UserID)
        {
            if (UserID.HasValue)
            {

            }
            else if (this.RouteData.Values["id"] != null)
            {
                long tempValue = 0;
                if (long.TryParse(this.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString(), out tempValue))
                {
                    UserID = tempValue;
                }
            }

            return View();
        }
```

Hope it helps.